# Binding from Set to <form:select> in SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am creating web using Spring MVC and I am still beginner with Spring. I have two entities with many to many relationship. in practice, I have UserGroup, which can have many or one (or none) UserAuthority I want to edit these relationships using form with multiple select. Creating new UserGroup entity or editing existing one works fine, with one small issue: when editing existing UserGroup, there are not select appropriate authorities in the select box. I've been working on this for more than a day with no success. Can someone please help me?

My model for entities is:

```
@Entity
public class UserGroup {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user_group_has_user_authority",
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_group_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_authority_id")})
    private Set<UserAuthority> authorities;
}
```

(I left out getters and setters, but I have them in my code)

and

```
public class UserAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String code;

    private String name;
}
```

(again, I left out setters and getters).

My form looks like this:

```
<form:form action="${action}" method="post" commandName="userGroup" id="user-group-form">
    <form:input readonly="true" cssClass="dn" path="id"/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="title">Title</form:label>
                <form:errors path="title" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="title"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="authorities">Authorities</form:label>
                <form:errors path="authorities" />    
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:select path="authorities" multiple="true" items="${authoritiesList}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

My contoller methods are following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editGroup", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public ModelAndView editGroup(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Long id = null;
    UserGroup userGroup = null;
    HashMap<String, Object> editModel = new HashMap<>(2);

    try {
        id = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("id"));
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    }
    if (id != null) {
        userGroup = groupsManager.get(id);
    } 

    UserGroupData userGroupData = groupsManager.createFromUserGroup(userGroup);

    editModel.put("userGroup", userGroupData);
    editModel.put("authoritiesList", getAuthoritiesList());

    return new ModelAndView("/users/groupEdit", editModel);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/editGroup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateGroupAction(@ModelAttribute("userGroup") @Validated UserGroupData userGroupData, BindingResult result, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("userGroup", userGroupData);
        return "/users/groupEdit";
    }
    groupsManager.saveUserGroupData(userGroupData);
    return "redirect:/users/listGroup";
}

private Map <Long, String> getAuthoritiesList() {      //I also tried returning Map<String,String> but result was same.
    Map<Long,String> authorities = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (UserAuthority ua : authorityManager.getAll()) {
        authorities.put(ua.getId(), ua.getName());
    }
    return authorities;
}
```

Finnaly, I use this converter to create UserAuthority from String (actually I googled this somewhere, but it works :) )
    public class StringToUserAuthorityConverter implements Converter {

```
    /**
     * The string that represents null.
     */
    private static final String NULL_REPRESENTATION = "null";

    @Autowired
    private UserAuthorityDao authorityDao;

    @Override
    public UserAuthority convert(final String id) {
        if (id.equals(NULL_REPRESENTATION)) {
            return null;
        }
        Long lId = null;
        try {
            lId = new Long(id);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        }
        return authorityDao.find(lId);
    }
}
```

As I said, all creating and editing works, only problem I have is, that authorities already associated to group are not selected when editing existing group. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I found out two things, maybe it can help:

1) In html page, there is following field:

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="_authorities">
```

I read it should contains values of my authorities field form model, but no matter what, it always contains 1 in my case

2) If my form fails validation (that means if I don't enter Title, which is mandatory) form reloads with error message, but select box is empty. Isn't it sign of something?

**EDIT 2**

I resolved point 2) from my last edit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in your `Authority` entity class. It's because `Set` (and other collections) check for object equality and this is how Spring marks already selected fields.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode

Answer (score 1):

So I made one ugly solution. Although it works, code isn't as nice as I'd like it to be. I edited my form in jsp like this:

```
<form:select path="authorities" multiple="true" >
     <c:forEach var="authority" items="${authoritiesList}">
         <c:choose>
             <c:when test="${userGroup.authorities.contains(authority) eq true}">
                 <option value="${authority.id}" selected="selected">${authority.name}</option>
             </c:when>
             <c:otherwise>
                 <option value="${authority.id}">${authority.name}</option>
             </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

But there has to better way...

Comment: Had a similar problem. I have 3 select tags on 1 form and only the last one on the page would bind properly. Still can't figure out why even though they follow same mapping pattern fro ManyToMany, etc. So I hacked them too.

Answer (score 0):

you should use AutoPopulatingList for conversion, this feature is available in spring for list data conversion to model list. [example](http://java-sandbox.cloudfoundry.com/autopopulatinglist)

Comment: I tried that but it behaves exactly the smae as while using Set. Updates, creating works, but options in the select are never selected. I'll update my questions with small new observations in a few minutes